# Regex: not all BLANKS but allow certain characters, with limit

Tags: regex, whitespace

Trying to come up with a Regex, or combination of Regex, that returns False if a) they have only entered only BLANK(s), or they  b) entered "non-legal" characters.  Lastly, the number of characters has a set limit.

The closest I have thus far is below.  Where it fails is that it does not count any leading spaces; only the non-BLANKs are counted, and so it fails.  Using js.

```js
const reg = /^(**[ ]***[!-~\u2018-\u201d\u2013\u2014]){1,10}$/;
```

**EDIT**: I think the above is incorrect, and I meant to post this:

```js
const re4 = /^(?!\s*$)[!-~\u2018-\u201d\u2013\u2014]{1,10}$/;
```

EDIT 2: this has less clutter; allow space and all other 'standard' keyboard chars:

```
const re5 = /^(?!\s*$)[!-~]{1,10}$/;
```

So, this says you can enter a bunch of spaces, and must include at least 1 other character from the list following; but the {1,10} only counts the non-spaces and so I can end up with too many in total.
EDIT:

So, using re5 above --

```
s = ' ';  // should fail
s = ' blah blah'; // should pass
s = '  blah blah';  // should fail, as there are 11 characters
```

Comment: Please post sample input that should match, and input that should not match.

Comment: Here is 1 space and 10 characters (total 11).  Returns True when I need to return False since total is > 10.    Remove single quotes:  ' 123456789A'

Comment: Please post **in your question** clear examples of sample input that should match, and clear examples of input that should not match, formatted as "code"

Comment: @Bohemian  Done, thanks!

Comment: So put simply, it is that the input should be from 1 to 10 chars long and can't be all blanks?

Comment: @Bohemian  Yes!  Thank you.

Comment: @Bohemian   Yes, absolutely correct.

Comment: well, my answer gives you that

Answer (score 0):

*Update 2*: After learning that you cannot invert the match result in code, here's one last suggestion using negative lookahead (like you already tried yourself).

This regex matches only strings of 1-10 non-banned characters that are *not* all whitespace:

```
const re4 = /^(?!\s+$)[^\!-\~\u2018-\u201d\u2013\u2014]{1,10}$/
```

---

*Update 1*: Use this regex to match all-whitespace string OR strings longer than 10 chars OR strings containing bad characters:

```
const re4 = /(^\s+$|^.{11,}$|[\!-\~\u2018-\u201d\u2013\u2014])/
```

---

I understand that you want to impose a length restriction via regex. I would suggest against that and recommend using `str.length` instead.

This regex will match whitespace-only strings and strings containing one or more bad characters:

```
const re4 = /(^\s+$|[\!-\~\u2018-\u201d\u2013\u2014])/;
```

*Regarding prohibition of all-whitespace strings*: Instead of packing it into a regex, you might consider using something more explicit like `if (s.trim().length == 0)`. IMO this makes your intention clearer and your code propably more readable, leaving you with this easy to read regex:

```
# matches any string containing a *bad* character
const re4 = /[\!-\~\u2018-\u201d\u2013\u2014]/;
```

If you use trim for the all-whitespace check, you might convert your regex into a positive assertion, even with length restriction:

```
# matches any string consisting of 1-10 characters not considered *bad*
const re4 = /^[^\!-\~\u2018-\u201d\u2013\u2014]{1,10}$/;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  This is part of a framework of sorts, from which Regex is pulled from a DB based on a Question being answered, so can't do as you suggested.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to include an all-in version. Does this meet all your requirements?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  It treats all BLANKS as True, adding other characters returns False.  Thank you for trying!

Comment: So in your code you can't even invert the match result? I'm too short of the issue context, then.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(?:\s*\S){1,10}\s*$`
Allow 1-10 non whiter, change `\S` to allow chars

Answer (score 0):

To match the input when it’s from 1 to 10 chars long and can't be all blanks, use a negative look ahead to assert not all blanks:

```
^(?! *$).{1,10}
```

If you want to restrict allowable chars, change the dot to a suitable character class of allowable chars.

Comment: I tried the above with ' 1234567899' and it failed.  const re6 = /^(?! *$).{1,10}/;

Comment: @aintnothin how *exactly* did it "fail"?

Comment: function testPattern2(myStr) {
  const re6 = /^(?! *$).{1,10}/;
  if (re6.test(myStr) == 0) {
    alert('No Good!');
     } else {
    alert('Good!');
     }
 }

Comment: @aintnothin that’s the code (js?), but how did it *fail*? Error? Matched when it shouldn’t have? Didn’t match when it should have? If a matching problem, exactly what was the input and expected result?